# 424 Error Access 2010 - Multiselect Listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create VBA code for multiselect listbox in Access 2010- so that when the user clicks on the command button, the program inputs the selection(s) into an array and then for each selection the user made (each "true" value), prints out the name of the selection (which in this case is a topic) and any items that are linked to that selection.  I have two tables:  Topics and Items. Each item is linked to up to three topics in the Topic table.

My problem is I keep on getting "Runtime error 424 Object Required". I simplified the code considerably so that I can narrow down the source of the current problem. The code I'm currently working with is:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim I As Integer

For I = 0 To TopicsL.ListCount-1
     If TopicsL.Selected(I) Then
     Debug.Print “Hello”
 End If
Next I
End Sub
```

TopicsL is my listbox's name. The error seems to be in the following line: 
For I = 0 To TopicsL.ListCount-1

Do I need to modify the "TopicsL.ListCount" further?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path to the listbox eg `form1.TopicsL.ListCount - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have named/spelt the Listbox correctly? To make sure you are referencing the correct listbox, use Me. When you type Me. then all the contols, properties, methods available to the Form will be listed, and when you start typing "top" it will lsit the ListBox name. If it did not, now you know there is some problem. If it did, make sure that the properties of the ListBox are set right.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Integer
    For iCtr = 0 To Me.TopicsL.ListCount - 1
        If Me.TopicsL.Selected(iCtr) Then _
            Debug.Print "Hello World !!"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I got the Me. to work -it found my ListBox.  When I ran the code a pop-up box came up - "Macros" with a text box for "Macro Name" and some buttons (Run, Cancel, Step Into, etc.). I seem to have created code in two places - one bit of code is under Microsoft Access Class and the other under Modules. I don't remember how or why I did this, but it seems to be creating problems. I don't know how to delete the class and/or module pages that I created, though I can erase the code from the pages. I am not sure which I need- a class or module or both. I read a bit about them but was left confused.

Comment: Its very confusing when you describe it. The first part you said it came up with Debug, Step Into sounds like you have encountered a Run Time error. Just click Debug, and it will take you to the line of code that is causing the problem.

Comment: All of the buttons in the pop-up box that comes up are greyed out / inactive. I can put text into the Macro Name textbox and press a button, but I'm not sure what text to put in or why this pop-up box is coming up when I try to run the code.

Comment: Basically, what is happening is that when I go to run my code in VBA editor, I press "Run" and a Macro box comes up and I don't know why. It is the same box that comes up when you go to "Tools" menu at top of the VBA editor and select "Macros...".  Even if my code is now just to print a simple "Hello World!" - nothing happens when I go to run the code except that the Macro pop-up box appears. Can you help, please?